# Date Comparsion in Matlab

Tags: matlab, date

I would like to check whether the date I pass in into a function comes after 01/02 or 01/08. How do i do that in Matlab? This comparsion does is independent of the year.

Need some guidance on this.

Btw, how do u calculate the difference between dates irregardless of year?

Comment: A simple google search will give you [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html)

Comment: i know but it will include the year as well...I don't want to include the year...

Comment: you can use datenum with date formart as `mm/dd`. No need to include year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html), with a format specifier if you want to be explicit:

```
D0 = datenum('01/02','mm/dd'); % current year is inferred (irrelevant)
D1 = datenum('01/08'); % 'mm/dd' is inferred
```

This allows you to test with regular comparison operators:

```
>> D = datenum('01/03')
>> D > D0
ans =
     1
>> D > D1
ans =
     0
```